# Extra quotes appearing in Java String at runtime

Tags: java, android, string

I am working on an Android application using SQLite, and I have a Contract class defined for my table and column names, suggested per the Android developer tutorial.

I have run into some strange behavior where an extra set of enclosing quotes is being added to all of my Strings in this contract. eg:

```
public final class Contract {
    public Contract() {};
    public static abstract class TABLE_Entry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I am debugging this application, the string `COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP` is a String with the value `""timestamp""`, with a length of 11 and where the first and last characters are double quotes, rather than simply `"timestamp"` (length of 9, no quotes in string). This works fine when used in SQL statements, but I would like to be able to use these String elsewhere.

I have already implemented a workaround, but I want to know why this is occurring in the first place.

Comment: That should not be possible. A `static final String` is a compile-time constant and cannot be modified. Can you describe how you're concluding the string is being modified?

Comment: What is the final output you are seeing? It should be just timestamp without any ".
What tool are you using to develop the application?

Comment: *"This works fine when used in SQL statements"* Just pointing out that in SQL strings use `'` not `"`.

Comment: I am writing this in eclipse, and using the eclipse debugger to view the content of the string. The display shows ""timestamp"" with a length of 11.